# Falcor - HTTPDataSource to post Json

Tags: falcor, falcor-router

Is it possible to post a Json file using the falcor.browser's model? I have used the get method in it. Below is what I require, but it is not working.

```
<script src="./js/falcor.browser.js"></script>
function registerUser() {
  var dataSource = new falcor.HttpDataSource("http://localhost/registerUser.json");
  var model = new falcor.Model({
      source: dataSource
  });

var userJson = {"name":"John","age":"35","email":"john@abc.com"};

model.
 set(userJson).
 then(function(done){
   console.log(done);
 });
```

This is the server.js code:

```
app.use('/registerUser.json', falcorExpress.dataSourceRoute(function (req, res) {
  return new Router([
    {
      route: "rating",
      get: function() {
           // Post call to external Api goes here
      }
    }
  ]);
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

The Model's [set()](http://netflix.github.io/falcor/doc/Model.html#set) method takes 1+ [pathValues](http://netflix.github.io/falcor/doc/global.html#PathValue), so reformat your `userJson` object literal into a set of pathValues.  Something like:

```
model.
 set(
   { path: ['users', 'id1', 'name'], value: 'John' },
   { path: ['users', 'id1', 'age'], value: 35 },
   { path: ['users', 'id1', 'email'], value: 'john@abc.com' }
 ).
 then(function(done){
   console.log(done);
 });
```

Second, your router must implement [set handlers](http://netflix.github.io/falcor/documentation/router.html) to correspond to the paths you are trying to set.  These handlers should also return pathValues:

```
  new Router([
    {
      route: 'users[{keys:ids}]["name", "age", "email"]',
      set: function(jsonGraph) {
          // jsonGraph looks like { users: { id1: { name: "John", age: 35, email: "john@abc.com" }
          // make request to update name/age/email fields and return updated pathValues, e.g.
          return [
              { path: ['users', 'id1', 'name'], value: 'John' },
              { path: ['users', 'id1', 'age'], value: 35 },
              { path: ['users', 'id1', 'email'], value: 'john@abc.com' },
          ];
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Given that your DB request is likely asynchronous, your route get handler will have to return a promise or observable.  But the above should work as a demonstration.

#### Edit

You can also use [route pattern matching](http://netflix.github.io/falcor/documentation/router.html) on the third path key if the number of fields gets large, as was demonstrated above on the second id key.

```
    {
      route: 'users[{keys:ids}][{keys:fields}]',
      set: function(jsonGraph) {
        /* jsonGraph looks like
           {
             users: {
               id1: { field1: "xxx", field2: "yyy", ... },
               id1: { field1: "xxx", field2: "yyy", ... },
               ...
            }
          }
        */
      }
    }
```

Comment: I understand your point, but does it mean that if I have a form of around 10 fields - then I have to go on extending the route? Like route: 'users[{keys:ids}]["name", "age", "email", "address","mobile","phone".....]'??

Comment: Is there any working example of Falcor? where Falcor (Node/Express) is using an External Api to GET/POST data? Typically using the falcorExpress.dataSourceRoute method along with request-promise package.

Comment: Updated my answer to handle large number of fields.  As for a working example, here's an example router with get/set/call handlers and a simple SQLite db backend: https://github.com/jameslaneconkling/falcor-sql-router/blob/master/falcor/resourcesById.js

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was really helpful. I was able to successfully use the GET, CALL methods in falcor here https://github.com/vasancec/falcorRouting. For now, I have used "var data" in server.js file instead of API/DB. Currently I am trying to use the $ref data type and I am struck in that. Would be posting a separate question for that.